# How to change where file from a github repository is locally stored?

Tags: c, github, repository, push, keil

A partner and I are working on a lab for a class in C using Keil. Each student who does this project has the same starter files and folders that contain the files for each project. We have a single project file, Project.c, that we both edit. My partner uploaded his file to GitHub. When I downloaded the GitHub file to my computer, it created a new folder inside the project folder where the shared Project.c file is stored. However, I need the file to be in the project folder, which is above the GitHub folder. Is there a way for me to move the file to the project folder yet still be able to push/pull?

Comment: Give actual details - the local directory structure and the remote directory structure for example. And why do you need your local tree to be different to the remote tree? That's not how projects should usually be set up. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kaylum I apologize, but I'm not sure what you mean. The directory structure is a folder with a single file. When I clone the repository so that I can edit it locally, it creates a folder on my computer with that file in it. However, I need that file (which I now have a local copy of) to be somewhere else that isn't that folder.

Comment: Are you sure that the remote actually has a folder? Generally when you clone git will by default create a destination folder using the remote project name. So we need to know whether the remote really has a folder or whether that's just git creating it for you. If it is the latter then simply tell git not to create the folder by using `.` as the destination directory when cloning. But without seeing details it is difficult to be certain what your exact scenario is. That is why it is always good to provide an exact concrete example rather than an abstract description.

Comment: Sound like you did: `cd /home/me/projdir ; git clone ...` and it created a subdir (e.g. `foodir`). So, now you have: `/home/me/projdir/foodir`. In _that_ directory, you will have (e.g.) `.git` and `file1`, `file2`, ... So, do this (from `projdir`): `mv foodir/.* foodir/* . ; rmdir foodir`. Now, from `/home/me/projdir`, you should be able to execute `git` commands as you like (e.g. `git pull`, `git status`, etc.)

Comment: It would be nice if `projdir` had the same name as `foodir`, but it's not absolutely necessary. You could do: `mkdir /home/me/projects ; cd /home/me/projects ; git clone ...` And, then, `cd foodir` where `foodir` is the _global_ name of the project.